# Is there a classification of the group of units in every ring of order $p^2$?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a finite ring (with unity) of order $p^2$, where $p$ is a prime.
I know that there are exactly 11 rings of this order.
My question is the following:
Is there a classification of the group of units in every ring of order $p^2$?
If the answer is yes, please recommend a reference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Only 4 of the 11 rings of order $p^2$ have a unity.

$$
\mathbb{Z}/(p^2)
$$

$$
\mathbb{F}_{p^2}
$$

$$
\mathbb{F}_{p}\times \mathbb{F}_{p}
$$

$$
\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(X^2)
$$

See answers to the following question for an explanation:
[Classifying Unital Commutative Rings of Order $p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109506/classifying-unital-commutative-rings-of-order-p2)

For case 1: the group of units is $C_{p^2-p}$

Source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Cyclic_case

For case 2: the group of units is $C_{p^2-1}$

Source: [Finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic)

For case 3: the group of units is $C_{p-1}\times C_{p-1}$

Source: [Group of units of direct sum of rings is isomorphic to direct sum of the groups of units](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191471/group-of-units-of-direct-sum-of-rings-is-isomorphic-to-direct-sum-of-the-groups)

For case 4: an element $a+bX+(X^2)$ in this ring is a unit iff $a\neq 0$, and the group is again cyclic $C_{p^2-p}$.

Sources:

[Units in polynomial quotient ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667329/units-in-polynomial-quotient-ring)

[Is the group of units of a finite ring cyclic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/is-the-group-of-units-of-a-finite-ring-cyclic)

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373134?seq=1

Comment: +1 Excellent referencing!

Answer (score 5):

If $\{0\}$ is maximal then its a field of $p^2$ elements and it's known that the units are the cyclic group of order $p^2-1$.

If $\{0\}$ is not maximal, then there is a maximal ideal of order $p$, call it $M$.  If $M$ is unique, then $R\setminus M$ is the set of units, and as a group of order $p^2-p$.  This case breaks further down into the case where the characteristic is $p$ or the characteristic is $p^2$.

If $M$ is not unique, then there's another maximal ideal $M'$ such that $M\cap M'=\{0\}$ (arguing by orders.). In this case $R\cong F_p\times F_p$, and the group of units is obviously $C_{p-1}\times C_{p-1}$.

Comment: In the second case $R\setminus M$ has size $p^2-p=p(p-1)$

Comment: @halrankard Ah, yes, silly mistake. you're right.